# How to pass response from ajax to datapoint for canvasjs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, canvasjs

Im trying to pass response value from ajax to datapoint for chartjs

I got an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: c.dataPoints.sort is not a function

The response output is

> [{"label":"5S","y":29},{"label":"Ergonomic","y":11},{"label":"Fall","y":2},{"label":"Environment","y":2},{"label":"PIT","y":2},{"label":"Chemical","y":1},{"label":"Electrical","y":1},{"label":"Machine","y":1},{"label":"N/A","y":1}]

the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //$('.chart1').load("changeChart1.php");
        $("#filter_A1, #filter_A2, #filter_A3").change(function(){
            var f1year = $("#filter_A1").val();
        var f1month = $("#filter_A2").val();
        var f1sort = $("#filter_A3").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "process/changeChart1.php",
                data: {
                f1year: f1year,
                f1month: f1month,
                f1sort: f1sort
              },
                success: function(response) {
                var area = new CanvasJS.Chart("area", {
      animationEnabled: true,
      legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
      },
      data: [{
        type: "scatter",
        markerType: "square",
        yValueFormatString: "0 Issues",
        dataPoints: response
      }]
    });

        area.render();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing dataType: 'json' so

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "process/changeChart1.php",
                data: {
                f1year: f1year,
                f1month: f1month,
                f1sort: f1sort
              },
```